# Excel VBA Assigning value to another cell on another worksheet using offset

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA.  My goal is to create a macro that will add a new column in the "computer languages" section (prior to the operating systems section).  It adds it on the active worksheet, then there is another worksheet called "Filtering" which is used to filter out results and it needs to be added in the same section (it's not exactly in the same spot as the main worksheet).

So far, it adds the column in both worksheets correctly.  I just need to insert the value.  It inserts it correctly on the main worksheet, but fails to enter the value on the "Filtering" worksheet.

Can anyone tell me why my code fails with

> Error 438

It's probably really simple.  But again, I've only programmed with this this week.

```
Sub newComputerLanguage()
newCL = InputBox("New Computer Language Name")

    Dim CLheaderFiltering As Range
    Dim OSheaderFiltering As Range
    Dim CLheader As Range
    Dim OSheader As Range

    Set CLheaderFiltering = Worksheets("Filtering").Range("O4:HC4").Find("Computer Languages")
    Set OSheaderFiltering = Worksheets("Filtering").Range("O4:HC4").Find("Operating Systems")
    Set CLheader = Range("Q5:HC5").Find("Computer Languages")
    Set OSheader = Range("Q5:HC5").Find("Operating Systems")

    If OSheader Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "Operating Systems column was not found."
      Exit Sub
    Else
      Worksheets("Filtering").Columns(OSheaderFiltering.Column).Offset(, 0).Resize(, 1).Insert
      Columns(OSheader.Column).Offset(, 0).Resize(, 1).Insert

      OSheader.Offset(, -1).Value = newCL
      Worksheets("Filtering").OSheaderFiltering.Offset(, -1).Value = newCL  'FAILS HERE!
      OSheader.Offset(1, -1).Select

    End If
End Sub
```

I would think it should work by simply adding Worksheets.

Comment: You have `Set` OSheaderFiltering to be a range on the Worksheets("Filtering") worksheet. You do not need to restate Worksheets("Filtering"). `OSheaderFiltering.Offset(, -1).Value = newCL` should be sufficient.

Comment: Why do you have .Resize(,1) in the statementd with Insert? Also, you already have a reference to the column that you are selecting - this code would be equivalent: `OSheaderFiltering.EntireColumn.Insert` which will insert a new column before it.

Comment: I don't think the statement `Worksheets("Filtering").OSHeaderFiltering....` will work. `OSHeaderFiltering` is a variable in its own right, it's not a property of the worksheet. That's most likely why you are getting Error 438

Comment: . . . as indeed I see @Jeeped has already pointed out.

Comment: SOLVED:  Thanks Jeeped.  I didn't know that it's been set already.  As far as why it's resized for JohnRC's question, I don't know.  I found the code to do what I needed, which was to add a column in between a specific cell, so I used it.